# How to make inheritance using Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, database-design

I am creating an webshop app. I have a tech shop with products that are for example CPUs, GPUs, keyboards, mouses etc. All of them have common attributes - id, description, name, but also their own, custom attributes - mouses have dpi and keyboards switch type etc.

[image]

What would be the best way to create a database and tables in Laravel?

I tried without inheritance first, but it seems complicated when I want to search a product by id, because I also need to pass product type (table name).

What would be the best approach for this problem?

Comment: I think using morphing for 'inheritance' is the way to go in eloquent. I always use this tutorial, hope it helps. [Handling model inheritance in eloquent models](https://chuniversiteit.nl/programming/inheritance-in-eloquent-models#multi-table-inheritance)

Comment: Ok, I will take a look. The problem is that I'm not even sure if I need inheritance - products are always displayed in rows by category. On the other hand, I need to fetch wanted product by his id, but also to know its category type - that way it would be easier that everything is in the same table with lots of attributes and most of them are null (mouse would have switch_type NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main model should look something like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['productable_id', 'productable_type', 'manufacturer_id', 
                       'model',  'price', 'description'];

public function productable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then, lets say in GPU model in its fillable you add its attribute that differs the GPU from the main table

```
protected $fillable = ['memory'];
```

You also need this in GPU controller:

```
public function component(): MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(Component::class, 'productable');
}
```

For the component migration, you should make attributes like productable_type and productable_id. The key is in using morph like some other comments said.

Then, in GPU controller, your index method should start with something like this:

```
$gpus = GPU::with('component')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As one comment has already suggested. Polymorphic relationships are the ideal solution to your requirement.
[See docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

You would want a `productable` relationship to the `Product` as an umbrella to your products holding the shared properties like, `description`, `price`, `stock_level` etc.

Build your tables something like:

```
keyboard
    id - integer
    name - string
    switch_type - string/enum/foreignId
    type - string/enum/foreignId
    wired - tinyInt
 
mouse
    id - integer
    name - string
    type - string/enum/foreignId
    wired - tinyInt
 
products
    id - integer
    description - string
    price - integer
    stock_level - integer
    productable_id - integer
    productable_type - string
```

And your models

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
 
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the parent productable model (Mouse or Keyboard).
     */
    public function productable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
 
class Keyboard extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the Keyboard's Product.
     */
    public function product(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Product::class, 'productable');
    }
}
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
 
class Mouse extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the Mouse's Product.
     */
    public function product(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Product::class, 'productable');
    }
}
```

Then you can call the product model to get all products with their shared listing details. Then leverage the `productable` relationship to load in their type-specific details.

Also, consider having an `Productable` trait on your `Mouse` and `Keyboard` models to allow you to define shared methods when required.
**EDIT**: `Productable` is probably not the best name for such a trait, maybe `HasProductMethods` or `IsProduct`

**Going a step further:**
If you then define a `Productable` interface, you can treat your `Mouse` and `Keyboard` classes as `Productable` items. This is really useful when you want to type-constrain your methods parameters but you want methods that can accept a `Mouse` or `Keyboard` instance.

For example, you may want to add these items to a basket. The `Basket` would have an `addItem()` method. Instead of having to resolve your related `Product` in order to pass a `Mouse` or `Keyboard` instance, your can type-hint the `Productable` interface and simply pass the `Mouse` or `Keyboard.